# How do I plot the respective data on each trendline point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this data:

```
Years        Value
2016-12-31   -495982.0
2017-12-31   -405549.0
2018-12-31   -351541.0
2019-12-31   -283790.0
```

When i plot the data I have a trend line with points representing the data for each year.
For example:

[image] 
My question is, how do I plot the value amount for each year on each data point. So for example for 2016-12-31 I would like to plot -495982.0 on the first trend line point.

This is what my code looks like:

```
ax.set_title('Plotting the keg')
ax.set_xlabel('Years')
ax.set_ylabel('keg value')
plt.plot(Years,Value, '-o', color='orange')
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.kegger.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p:format(int(x), ',')))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a loop and use the ax.annotate() function, and play around with the placement of the annotation as well as any text you want to include besides the y-value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Years': ['2016-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2019-12-31'],
    'Value': [-495982.0, -405549.0, -351541.0, -283790.0]})
Years = df['Years']
Value = df['Value']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Plotting the keg')
ax.set_xlabel('Years')
ax.set_ylabel('keg value')
plt.plot(Years,Value, '-o', color='orange')

# annotate by looping through each (x, y) coordinate
for index in range(len(Years)):
    ax.annotate(Value[index], xy=(Years[index],Value[index]), color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey mate @Derek O thanks for your response. When i run the code i get an error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: That's strange because it worked for me. Is the type consistent in the Years and Values columns of your df? Maybe Years should be in datetime format (although mine are strings), and values should be some type of number (float or int).

Comment: Okay so i checked the datatype for each of my columns and the years column is a: datetime64[ns] and the values column is a: float64

Comment: If i were to change the Years column to a string like: data['Years'].astype(str) I am still getting the error

Comment: When you assign a list of strings to a df column, the default data type is object which matplotlib handles fine. But data['Years'].astype(str) will turn it into a string. Try something like pd.Series(data['Years'].astype(str)) which should be an object.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation mate. I followed exactly what you did and i still get the error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: If you copy and paste my code exactly, does it work? Does the TypeError only happen when you use your df? If you are using my code, check that whatever you use for the 'Years' variable says dtype: object

Comment: Yes the code works if i were to copy and paste. And Yes only when i use my df the typeError appears :/

Comment: Did you try: Years = pd.Series(data['Years'].astype(str)), and then check that 'Years' is of type object?

Comment: Yeah so I did check. This type is dtype: object

Comment: In the for loop if I were to print("its me",data[index]) I get the typeError. So for years the datatype is dtype: object and for value the datatype is: dtype: float64

Comment: I am going to accept this answer. For the issue I am facing i will ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated